# Algebraic approach to D'alembert wave solution

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}U(x+ct)+\frac{1}{2}U(x-ct)+\frac{1}{2}W(x+ct)-\frac{1}{2}W(x-ct) $$\par$$ 
=\frac{1}{2}U(x+ct)+\frac{1}{2}U(x-ct)+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}V(z)dz$$

I'm trying to move from the first expression to the second. I've managed to arrive at the first expression from the linear second-order wave equation.
Here, I can see that the second expression involves the fundamental theorem of calculus. What stumps me is the constant 'c' in the denominator, otherwise, my attempt would have correct.

It's been a long day, could someone help me?

Comment: What is the relation between $V$ and $W$?

Comment: I can only say that \frac{1}{2}(W(b)-W(a)) = Integral of V on the domain [a,b]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you are doing exactly, but let me guess. If I'm wrong, please clarify what your notations are, and what you are doing.

I guess you are solving the wave equation
$$
u_tt=c^2u_xx,\quad u(x,0)=U(x),\quad u_t(x,0)=V(x).
$$
Maybe you have solved the differential equation and found out that
$$
u(x,t)=f(x-ct)+g(x+ct)
$$
for some functions $f$ and $g$?

Then, matching with the initial conditions,
$$
U(x)=u(x,0)=f(x)+g(x),\quad V(x)=u_t(x,0)=-cf'(x)+cg'(x)
$$
Integrating the second condition (divided by $c$) from some constant $a$ (which will play no role in the end) to $x$,
$$
\frac{1}{c}\int_a^x V(z)\,dz = -f(x)+g(x).
$$
Now, we have a linear system to solve for $f$ and $g$. Subtracting the second equation from the first, we find that
$$
2f(x)=U(x)-\frac{1}{c}\int_a^x V(z)\,dz.
$$
Adding the equations we find that
$$
2g(x)=U(x)+\frac{1}{c}\int_a^x V(z)\,dz.
$$
Thus, dividing by $2$ and summing,
$$
\begin{aligned}
u(x,t)&=f(x-ct)+g(x+ct)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\bigl(U(x-ct)+U(x+ct)\bigr)+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}V(z)\,dz.
\end{aligned}
$$
In the last step, we used that $\int_a^{x+ct}V(z)\,dz-\int_a^{x-ct}V(z)\,dz=\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}V(z)\,dz$.

Comment: In "Integrating the second condition..", it looks like you are integrating with respect to spatial variable the time derivatives of $f$ and $g$ ($f'$ and $g'$). How can that yield $f$ and $g$? I am confused. :)